# How to reuse parts of long chain of pipe operators in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a set of chains of pipe operators (`%>%`) doing different things with different datasets.

For instance:

```r
dataset %>%
   mutate(...) %>%
   filter(...) %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   summarise() %>%
   etc...
```

If I want to reuse some parts of these chains, is there a way to do it, without just wrapping it into a function?
For instance (in *pseudocode* obviously):

```r
subchain <- filter(...) %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   summarise() 

# and then instead of the chain above it would be:
dataset %>%
   mutate(...) %>%
   subchain() %>%
   etc...
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to create a function with your selected pipes, and pipe to that? I think that would achieve what you want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Similar in syntax to desired pseudo-code:

```
library(dplyr)

subchain <- . %>% 
  filter(mass > mean(mass, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(name, gender, homeworld)

all.equal(
  starwars %>% 
    group_by(gender) %>% 
    filter(mass > mean(mass, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    select(name, gender, homeworld),
  starwars %>% 
    group_by(gender) %>% 
    subchain()
)
```

Using a dot `.` as start of a piping sequence. This is in effect close to function wrapping, but this is called a magrittr functional sequence. See `?functions` and try `magrittr::functions(subchain)`